# Transpose multiple columns to rows from different tables

Tags: sql-server, transpose

I'm trying to transpose multiple columns to rows from 2 tables and I don't know how to start.

I know how to UNPIVOT one table, just don't know how to join them; if that makes sense.

So I have a main table like this:

```
mainId  Date            Rd  HT      AT      C1  C2  C3  C4
12      8/9/19 20:00    1   POOL    WICH    0   0   2   0
13      8/10/19 12:30   1   HAM     MCIT    2   0   2   0
```

And a second table (linked to main table through mainId):

```
Id  mainId  MO_H    MO_D    MO_A    O0.5  ......-> there are like 180 columns; so dynamic SQL is needed here.
331 12      2.09    3.56    4.1     1.063
332 13      1.71    4.15    5.65    1.048
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
mainId  Date            Rd  HT      AT      Column1  Column2
12      8/9/19 20:00    1   POOL    WICH    MO_H     2.09
12      8/9/19 20:00    1   POOL    WICH    MO_D     3.56
12      8/9/19 20:00    1   POOL    WICH    MO_A     4.1
12      8/9/19 20:00    1   POOL    WICH    O0.5     1.063
13      8/10/19 12:30   1   HAM     MCIT    MO_H     1.71
13      8/10/19 12:30   1   HAM     MCIT    MO_D     4.15
13      8/11/19 12:30   1   HAM     MCIT    MO_A     5.65
13      8/12/19 12:30   1   HAM     MCIT    O0.5     1.048
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that will dynamically unpivot your data without actually using dynamic SQL.   This approach is XML ... the **JSON version** does **NOT** like your column name `[O0.5]`

Please NOTE you only need to exclude certain columns   `... not in ('Id','mainId')`

I should also add:  NULL values will be excluded.

**Example**

```
Select A.[mainId]
      ,A.[Date]
      ,A.[Rd]
      ,A.[HT]
      ,A.[AT]
      ,D.*
 From  Main  A
 Join  Second B on  A.mainId=B.mainId
 Cross Apply ( values ( convert(xml,(Select B.* for XML RAW)) ) ) C(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')  --<< use proper data type
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                 Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') not in ('Id','mainId')
             ) D
```

**Returns**

```
mainId  Date            Rd  HT      AT      Item    Value
12      8/9/19 20:00    1   POOL    WICH    MO_H    2.09
12      8/9/19 20:00    1   POOL    WICH    MO_D    3.56
12      8/9/19 20:00    1   POOL    WICH    MO_A    4.10
12      8/9/19 20:00    1   POOL    WICH    O.05    1.063
13      8/10/19 12:30   1   HAM     MCIT    MO_H    1.71
13      8/10/19 12:30   1   HAM     MCIT    MO_D    4.15
13      8/10/19 12:30   1   HAM     MCIT    MO_A    5.65
13      8/10/19 12:30   1   HAM     MCIT    O.05    1.048
```